# I cannot subscribe to my event using reflection

Tags: c#, events, reflection

I have a c# desktop app.

I load a DLL using reflection. The DLL is loaded as bytes.

I need to bind to the event in the DLL.

The eventInfo is null.

This is my code:

//in my DLL

```
namespace injectdll
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public delegate void delResponseEvent(string message);
        public static event delResponseEvent ResponseEvent;
        public static void hello()
        {
            ResponseEvent("hello andy");
        }
    }
}
```

//in my desktop app

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            byte[] bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\Users\Andrew\Desktop\testbytes\injectdll\injectdll\bin\Debug\injectdll.dll");
            Assembly program = Assembly.Load(bytes);
            Type type = program.GetType("injectdll.Class1");
            MethodInfo Method = program.GetTypes()[0].GetMethod("hello");
            type.InvokeMember("hello", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, System.Type.DefaultBinder, "", null);
            var eventInfo = program.GetType().GetEvent("ResponseEvent");

            //eventinfo is null?
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First thing to know when using `Reflection` methods that starts with `Get` is that they use `BindingFlags` combination to determine which members should be returned and the default is `instance` and `public` members. Now, since your method and the event is `static` and `public` so you need to specify those flags:

```
Type type = program.GetType("injectdll.Class1"); 
var flags = BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public;
MethodInfo Method = type.GetMethod("hello", flags);
var eventInfo = type.GetEvent("ResponseEvent", flags);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try overload with `BindingFlags` to search for **static** events.

```
var eventInfo = program.GetType().GetEvent("ResponseEvent",BindingFlags.Static);
```

or

```
var eventInfo = program.GetType().GetEvent("ResponseEvent",BindingFlags.Static|BindingFlags.Instance);
```

Comment: Do you actually know the answer or are you just guessing?

Comment: @BartoszKP by default reflection methods skip private / static properties. That's why there are overloads with more specific arguments defined.

Comment: @tchrikch You didn't answer my question. You provide two alternatives and it's not clear whether both work and what's the difference. Have you verified this? (I'm not implying that your answer is necessarily wrong).

Comment: you should use Public and Static flags.

Comment: I did not minus 1 you btw